# yum database corruption check/fix module

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for an Ansible module to identify Red Hat or CentOS yum database errors for "rpmdb open failed"?  I'm looking to proactively identify servers we patch regularly to know ahead of patching and report for us when this error occurs.  And then have Ansible fix the error. Has anyone seen this type of module/fix?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Such a module does not exist, however you could use the `list` parameter for the yum module. It won't perform any task other than a `yum list` on the package you provide, and the result will be successful whether or not the package is installed, unless of course you run into an `rpmdb` error.

You will need to ignore errors and register the result, like so:

```
    - yum:
        list: kernel
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: result

    - debug: var=result
```

The `result` variable will include `failed=true`, `msg`, and `stderr`, which together you should be able to use to identify an rpmdb error. Based on this identification, you can kick off a conditional `shell` task to fix the error.

Comment: Thanks very much Matt for your reply.  I can see how this will work well for us.  Appreciate the response!